# BackboneJS How to load more models in collection by using click event

Tags: backbone.js

How can I load more models into my Collection by using Backbone's click event method?

I have the following Collection:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response){
        return response.data.posts.slice(0,10);
    },
});
```

this gives me 10 models. So far so good, now I want to load additional 10 models into the collection each time I click a button. How can I achieve this?

inside my view I have added this:

```
events: {
    'click .more': 'showMore'
},
showMore: function(){
   // show more functionality  
},
```

What to do next? Please help...

Comment: this.collection.fetch({remove: false}) ?

Comment: hmm yeah, that somehow works, but it loads the same 10 models all over again

Comment: does backend provides you new set of models ?

Comment: Yes, the backend (or the API) provides many models, just for displaying purpose I want to display 10 to start with, then user can choose to see more or not

Comment: oh, so the back provides you for e.g 100 models, on start you want to render 0-10, second 10-20, third 20-30 and so on ?

Comment: @Evgeniy Yes, exactly! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58329/discussion-between-evgeniy-and-sht).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chat discussion goal is to get first 10 post from API JSON on button click. As response is dynamic we cant parse collection once and then slice it on every click, so one of solution use flag on collection instance to control collection array slice:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    step: 0,
    parse: function(response){
        var slice = response.data.posts.slice(this.step*10,(this.step+1)*10)
        this.step++;
        return slice;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is bad practice, you shouldn't be fetching the models every time and then slicing them, you should do it all at once and then return a filtered collection for rendering, or the requests should only be fetching 10 at a time

Comment: @DominicTobias, absolutely agree, this was the first question i've asked - can we parse collection ones and then render its slices. But author replied response is dynamic and its necessary to run fetch on every click